# How to display the data on server form textbox?

Tags: c#, sockets

I run my server succsessfully but when i prints data which i previously printed in console screen to address me what is going on , i want to display all that on text box , but it does not display, and when i close connection from client it displays all that information. why it happens .?

Here is my code

```
  public void GetData()
  {
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    string ipadd = getip();

    IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.15"); //use local m/c IP   address, and use the same in the client
    // IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipadd);
    txtip.Text = ipAd.ToString();
    txtport.Text = "3030";
    /* Initializes the Listener */
    TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 3030);

    /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */

    myList.Start();

    txtdata.Text = "The server is running at port 3030...";
    txtdata.Text = txtdata.Text + Environment.NewLine + "The local End point  is :" + myList.LocalEndpoint;
    txtdata.Text = txtdata.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Waiting for a   connection.....";



    Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();

     txtdata.Text = txtdata.Text + Environment.NewLine +"Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint;
    // txtdata.Text = "Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint;

    }
```

Look at the code above when i write data on console it works but the same i want to print on txtdata (textbox) but it doesn't print , till connection close by client.

Answer (score 0):

You're blocking the UI thread. Until your method finishes executing, the UI can't update, because it can only be updated from the UI thread.

You ideally want to use asynchronous I/O instead of blocking the UI thread. Or, worst case scenario, use a separate thread to handle the communication.

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 24221);
listener.Start();

txtdata.Text = "The server is running...";

var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
```

This code avoids blocking the UI thread - instead, the UI thread will be free to do whatever it needs to do until a client connects, which will cause the code execution to resume at the `await` point, again on the UI thread.

Also, try using the highest abstraction available - in this case, `AcceptTcpClient` instead of `AcceptSocket`. There's no need to muck around with raw sockets when `TcpClient` provides you with a simple stream-based interface.